# GNOME Wayland gestures not working

Tags: linux, gnome, xorg, opensuse, wayland

I use `Opensuse Tumbleweed` with `Gnome`. Normally with `Gnome`, you can always swipe from the top left corner of your screen to the middle to open activities. I mean with a `Touchscreen`.

**PROBLEM:**

The problem is, this gesture doesn't work with `Wayland`. When I use `Xorg`, this gesture works perfectly (but mousepad gestures won't work). I really want to use `Wayland`. But this simple gesture doesn't work.

**QUESTION:**

Is there any way to make the top left corner swiping gesture work in `Gnome Wayland`?